# Хранение файлов на сервере

Tags: php, mysql, yandex-disk

На сервере будет мало места, а вот файлов добавляться будет достаточно, чтобы его забить через месяц. Как лучше реализовать хранение файлов вне сервера?

Нужно:

- прикрепить файл к статье, новости и т.д.;
- файл находился вне сервера.

Мое предложение:

Создать аккаунт, к примеру, в **yandex disk**, записать его токен, к примеру, в отдельное поле пользователя (их будет 1-3 человека) и потом, при добавлении файла, когда выберу прикрепленный файл, его загрузит на диск, а ссылку вставить снизу статьи, как переход к файлу.

В итоге будет достаточно 10-15 гб для нормальной работы.

Как вам мой вариант? Можете лучше предложить?

Comment: > Как вам мой вариант? можете лучше предложить?

Он выливается в довольно большие трудозатраты. Ну и я с подозрением отношусь ко всем внешним сервисам (конечно, аптайм яндекс.диска меньше 99% за любой промежуток от недели и больше - маловероятное явление, но все равно внешний сервис для меня выглядит как штука, которая *теоретически может отвалиться*), поэтому при выборе "альтернативная конфигурация сервера или внешний сервис" выберу первое. Практически все нижние линейки VPS сейчас начинаются от 10-20 гб и стоят примерно как обычный хостинг.

Comment: Хостинг от Университета, там места больше не дадут...

Comment: @Юра Сучко Существует неплохая библиотека [thephpleague/flysystem](https://github.com/thephpleague/flysystem) - умеет работать, как с локальным хранилищем, так и с удалённым (FTP, AWS S3, Rackspace,...). Чтобы не обращаться повторно, умеет кэшировать файловую структуру (локально, либо key-value storage: memcached, redis,...).

Яндекса там, естественно, нет, но есть dropbox. Никто не мешает Вам написать адаптер для яндекс диска. Кстати, думаю, авторы данной библиотеки будут рады, и Вам плюс.

Answer (score 1):

Я думаю так и нужно делать.

Во-первых вы снимете нагрузку с сети, сервера и т.д. с помощью этого (пользователь пойдет загружать файл не от вас)

Во-вторых этот диск вы сможете так же использовать для бэкапов

П.С: Токен вам понадобиться только для того, чтобы напрямую работать с REST API Яндекс Диска. Вы можете просто опубликовать файл и в статье указать эту ссылку.

Comment: ссылка на статью - это хорошо, но стоило бы добавить суть решения (выжимку кода) в сам ответ, чтобы другие участники не воспринимали это как спам/рекламу личного блога.

Comment: Ссылка на статью - способ получить упорядоченную и наглядую последовательность действий, которую в кратком ответе невозможно разъяснить.

Comment: Значит вам стоит дать не краткий, а полноценный и развернутый ответ. и в нем разьяснить последовательность действий. Иначе - завтра вы забудете проплатить хостинг, и ваш ответ превратится в 404.